# spring boot console app: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am working on a spring boot console app, i was getting an error so i deleted .m2 repository and updated the maven project.

but after doing this i got some spring Apllication errors.
these errors went after adding spring boot dependency but still i am not able to run the app.

i am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

This is my pom file dependencies

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
<version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache commons collections dependency -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
<version>1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
<version>5.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate Validator Dependency -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Querydsl dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
<artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Hikari jdbc data surce -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Hikari jdbc data surce -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.el</groupId>
<artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1-b04</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Mysql connector -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
<artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
<version>4.10.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
<exclusions>
<!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
<exclusion>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Try doing mvn:clean and run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your **pom** file. Have a look at it. You have spring boot starter **v2** at the same time you have spring boot **v1** with spring auto-configure. Either go with **spring boot starters** or no. Don't mix dependencies like that.

Comment: i added spring boot dependency because i was getting error for SpringApplication class, before i had not added that dependency. without it i am getting error

Comment: i have deleted .m2/repository again and removed spring boot dependency

Comment: now i am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer

Comment: You have this error because you have a version mismatch. Check again to see what versions you have included. And update your answer to reflect your changes